# Is XBAP (WPF via webpage) dead?

Tags: wpf, xbap

I see a lot of XBAP related questions posted here without answer.
I know that Silverlight and WPF (desktop) applications exists, but don't remember seen one XBAP product.
Can anyone tell if XBAP is dead (no applications being developed/supported)?
It would be nice if any XBAP developers could give their opinion.

Comment: XBAP is not dead but as long as Google does not support it it is as dead as it can be... There is no Google Chrome support for XBAP as there are no plans for it in the foreseeable future. Plus minor browsers do not support it too. More than that there is no support for linux (like there is partially for Silverlight with the Moonlight project).

Comment: It is time to bury our dead. It is so dead, that it won't be resurrected on the day of judgment.  

- Signed,

A Long Lost XBAP Developer from 2015

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Xbap is ideal for developing line of business apps for large companies. I used to work in that environment, and ensuring everyone had the correct version of an app was a nightmare.

Unfortunately xbap is late to the party. Most companies have solved this problem with existing technologies (SMS Installers, click once etc), also these companies aren't IT based and don't change/upgrade technologies unless they have to (the IT department I used to work in still use VS2003 and have no plans to upgrade).

So, given the glacial pace these departments adopt "new" technologies, and given their reluctance to change development practises, it could be another 5 or 10 years before they write and deploy an xbap application.

So rather than being dead, I think xbap has a limited audience of late adopters.

Comment: +1, it is also too early, as Silverlight 5 is new and more attractive.

Comment: Silverlight is dead as well :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Silverlight

Comment: @OneWorld Well 11 years later, it is now ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯